# How does google understand the legitimacy of a website by user activity?

Tags: seo, google, google-search

How does google understand the legitimacy of a website by user activity? Apart from:

- total time spend on a particular webpage by users
- total clicks on the website by users
- total unique visitors

Answer (score 3):

They don't. They don't know that information unless you're using Google Analytics and [they have already stated that they don't use Google Analytics' data in their ranking algorithm](http://www.dotcult.com/does-google-analytics-affect-seo).

The closest thing you may find them using is click through rates on their site and time spent on a site before returning back to Google. There's been no official word on this but many SEOers like to speculate that these are actually ranking factors.

Comment: John, what is your personal experience and observation of time spent on a site as a factor of seo?

Comment: I have not seen anything that has shown how time on site affects SEO. That doesn't make it untrue or true. It just means as of right now I haven't seen anything to support that yet. Some will point to Google using the "block this site" functionality this way but I am not sold on that yet.